# Allow non-pixel art game handle pixel art (integer movement)

Tags: c#, game-engine, monogame

I'm making a 2D platform game engine with C# and MonoGame that uses floating point numbers for all of its maths. It works well so far, however I'd like to have the option of using the engine for a retro-style pixel art game, which is obviously best done with integer maths. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

The simplest method I can come up with is to do all the calculations with floating point numbers, but then when I draw each sprite, I round the position to the nearest multiple of the scale of the pixel art (for example, to the nearest 5 pixels for pixel art that is scaled 5x). This functions, but the movement of the player character on the screen doesn't feel smooth.

I've tried rounding the player position itself each time I update it, but this breaks my collision detection, causing the player to be stuck on the floor.

Maybe there's a standard way people achieve a solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://nielson.io/2015/08/the-pixel-grid-better-2d-in-unity-part-1/
TLDR; Create another object that aligns the sprite +- half a pixel to "snap" to full pixels. Should also work if you want your pixel size more than one actual pixel - e.g. for a **very** pixely look.

Comment: Sadly @ManfredRadlwimmer this method breaks my game. It's essentially what I was trying to do in aligning my objects each update.

Comment: This could only break if you apply this method to the GameObject with the RigidBody2D component. If you use this "within" your object to align only the sprites, the physics should be unaffected.

Comment: I'm not using any kind of rigid body dynamics. It's all done with position, speed and acceleration vectors. Old-school I guess you could say!

Comment: Actually, if the aim was to just align sprites, that's the result I have already achieved by lining them up in my Draw method. However it doesn't produce a result as smooth as if the underlying calculations had been integer-based.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for resurrecting an ancient question, but I think a very simple way to do this for both programmer and hardware using GPU triangle rasterization (I'm assuming you're using a GPU pipeline, as this is trivial otherwise) that most directly simulates the look and feel of old hardware rendering at 200p or so is just render your entire game to an offscreen texture that is that actual 200p resolution and perform your entire game logic, including collision detection, at that resolution. You can shift all the coordinates by half a pixel which, combined with nearest neighbor sampling, should get them to plot precisely at a desired pixel if you have to work in floating point.

Then just draw a rectangle with the offscreen texture to the screen scaled to the full display resolution using nearest neighbor sampling and integer-sized scalars (2x, 3x, 5x, etc). That should be so much simpler than scaling each individual sprite and tile.

This is assuming you want a full retro look and feel where you can't draw things at what would normally be sub-pixel positions (1 pixel increments after scaling 5x instead of 5 pixel increments, or even sub-pixel at full resolution). If you want something that feels more modern where the scaled up art would be able to transform (move, rotate, scale) and animate in single-pixel increments or even sub-pixel with floating point, then you do need to scale up every individual sprite and tile. I don't think that would feel so retro and low-res though, more like very modern with scaled up blocky pixel art. Operating at the original low resolution tends to impact not just the look of the game but the feel as well.